# removing regional language from Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

recently I faced a problem with my Windows 10 which is really annoying.

I am from Iran, but recently I have migrated to Canada. I used to have Persian and English (US) as my preferred languages. But now English (CA) is added, and I cannot remove it.

here is my list of languages: 
 [image: languages in bottom tab]

And when I go to language preferences, I do not see the English(CA) to remove. here is the picture:

[image]

does anyone know how can I remove one of these English languages?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution :)

You should manually add the unwanted language to your preferred list and then remove it. then it will be gone for good :)